# Unable to upload a logo in OTRS

Tags: linux, centos, otrs

I am new in this matter. I have installed OTRS on a server running CentOS which is setup in Singapore and I am doing my installation related work from Bangladesh by SSH.

I have installed OTRS successfully.  Now I am trying to change the logo in customer portal. In which way I will do that? By pasting jpeg file in the Linux server folder or any other way?

Comment: If there's no logo changing option in settings, then checking where the link points and changing that image should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so new, and writing this answer from The Netherlands. :D

See this article below:

http://blog.otrs.org/2012/03/16/otrs-tips-tricks-custom-branding-the-customer-portal/

You can either put your logo in /opt/otrs/var/http/htdocs/skins/Customer/default/img or you can put your logo on some webserver and add the http(s) link in the configuration as indicated in the article.